# Can I use my laptop's bluetooth as a bluetooth dongle for my desktop?

Tags: laptop, bluetooth, desktop

I bought a Lego Wedo 2.0 Kit that requires Bluetooth on the device to connect to the Lego Block.

What I want is to use my laptop's internal Bluetooth on my main desktop PC. So I can use the Lego Block.

Any ideas of how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No. Bluetooth is a piece of hardware. There is not a practical way to use the laptop hardware on a desktop computer without Bluetooth.

**Solution:**  Really quite easy.  Get a USB Bluetooth adapter (inexpensive ones are available) and install on your desktop computer. That will work fine.

Comment: I'm not referring to do that. What I mean is to use some kind of program that has sends over Wi·Fi the Bluetooth connections that my laptop receives. Like, there are programs that manage Bluetooth connections like the one that might supply the manufacturer. Some kind of program like that would be awesome!

Comment: You cannot pair the laptop Bluetooth to the Desktop wireless. To pair Bluetooth requires Bluetooth on both devices. Bluetooth is different wireless so you need to put Bluetooth on the desktop computer.

Comment: You could RDC into it… but honestly, just buy a BT dongle for the desktop.